# Store users credentials inside of local storage | React, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage, jwt

When a user logs in he/she gets a token and if I `console.log` that token with `jwt_decode` **without** redirecting the user to the root path I can see the users mail, name, etc from my `console.log`, but if I redirect the user to the root path the `console.log` disappears after the user has been redirected.

```
export function login(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_IS_LOADING' })
    axios
      .post(`${settings.hostname}/tokens`, data)
      .then(res => {
        const token = res.data
        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: token })
        setAuthorizationToken(token)
        var decoded = jwt_decode(token)
        console.log('DECODED', decoded) // Getting an output when the line below is commented out
        // window.location.href = '/'
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', payload: err })
        console.log('Error:', err)
      })
  }
}
```

So I wonder why this is happening, and how I can solve it.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you sure the console.log isn't firing, but then you are redirecting immediately after so that the console is cleared? Try preserving the log and you should see the console.log

Answer (score 3):

changing the window.location is like doing a browser refresh, it will erase your console output the same way that refreshing your page will. you can get around this by checking "preserve log" in your chrome devtools options